# Get the value of text and remove the previous stored one upon click of another in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

everyone
I am trying to do a private chat system with Jquery, ajax and php. My system works in such a way that if a user click thumbnails of other users, the text is stored in a variable in Jquery and passed on to PHP. This is then used to get the private messages btwn the two users.

But my problem is if User C clicks A and later on Clicks B. Messages from A interlopes into messages from B for every 10 secs or so. How Do I stop this?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      $(".getuser").click(function() {

        var value = $(this).text();


        load_comment();

        function load_comment() {
          $.ajax({

            url: "getMessage.php",
            method: "GET",
            data: {
              'getvalue': value
            },
            success: function(data) {

              $('.chat-history').html(data);

              ///upon success scroll to bottom of message
              $("#bottom").get(0).scrollIntoView({
                behavior: "smooth",
                block: "end",
                inline: "nearest"
              });

            }

          });
          setTimeout(function() {
            load_comment();
          }, 5000);
        }

      });
```

Comment: You understand that by doing the setTimeout inside the load_comment method, you are creating an infinite loop, yes?  And every time you click a user, you are creating a brand new infinite loop that does not stop/replace the previous one(s)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //scope the user variable outside the click handler so it is shared by all instances
  //of the click handler invocation
  var user;
  var timeout;
  
  $(".getuser").click(function() {
    //clear the timeout that may be waiting
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    
    user = $(this).text();
    //store a reference to the user locally that will not change
    var thisUser = user;

    load_comment();

    function load_comment() {
      $.ajax({
        url: "getMessage.php",
        method: "GET",
        data: {
          'getvalue': value
        },
        success: function(data) {
          $('.chat-history').html(data);

          ///upon success scroll to bottom of message
          $("#bottom").get(0).scrollIntoView({
            behavior: "smooth",
            block: "end",
            inline: "nearest"
          });
        }
      });
      
      //only continue the loop if the user did not change
      if (user === thisUser) {
        //store the timeout so it can be cancelled
        timeout = setTimeout(load_comment, 5000);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to cancel your timer of `load_comment` when you clicked the user.

In your php, you have to identify the message of user. And only response the specify user's message to client.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      var t = null;
      $(".getuser").click(function() {
        var value = $(this).text();
        load_comment();

        function load_comment() {
          $.ajax({
            url: "getMessage.php",
            method: "GET",
            data: {
              'getvalue': value
            },
            success: function(data) {
              $('.chat-history').html(data);

              ///upon success scroll to bottom of message
              $("#bottom").get(0).scrollIntoView({
                behavior: "smooth",
                block: "end",
                inline: "nearest"
              });
            }
          });
          clearTimeout(t);
          t = setTimeout(function() {
            load_comment();
          }, 5000);
        }
      });
```

Comment: This cancels the timeout right before it starts a new one, which it would have only executed if it was the first time, or the timeout has already transpired and caused the invocation.  Also this does not address the multiple requests issue by clicking different users.